# Having trouble mocking methods on interfaces

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

Getting the following error trying to use `CallTo()` and `.Returns()` on methods of interfaces.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1929  'IReturnValueArgumentValidationConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Returns' and the best extension method overload 'ReturnValueConfigurationExtensions.Returns(IReturnValueConfiguration>, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IReturnValueConfiguration>'   CareControls.Ivis.Tests G:\Ivis\CareControls.Ivis.Tests\Framework\AbIo\TimerHandlerTests.cs 105 Active

Here is the test: I added comments to show what kind each type was and where the compiler errors were occurring.

```
[Fact]
public void Reads_AbPlc_at_each_inputs_label()
{
    var abPlc = A.Fake<AbPlc>(); // interface
    var input1 = A.Fake<ToggleUi>(); // interface
    var input2 = A.Fake<ToggleUi>(); // interface
    var w2 = A.Fake<MethodWeb>(); // class
    var f = this.fixture;
    input1.Label = f.Create<string>();
    input2.Label = f.Create<string>();
    A.CallTo(() => this.ui.Inputs)
        .Returns(new LinkedListLot<ToggleUi>(
            new[]
            {
                input1,
                input2
            }));
    var a = f.Create<bool>();
    A.CallTo(() => input1.GetHashCode())
        .Returns(0xFF); // error
    A
        .CallTo(() => abPlc.Read(input1.Label))
        .Returns(false); // error

    A.CallTo(() => w2.RegisterDependency(null, null))
        .Returns(false); // compiles fine
    var w = this.web;
    w.RegisterDependency(new UiReaderWriter());
    w.RegisterDependency(abPlc);

    this.handler.Handle(
        this.ui);

    A
        .CallTo(() => abPlc.Read(input1.Label))
        .MustHaveHappened();
    A
        .CallTo(() => abPlc.Read(input2.Label))
        .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

One last comment: these interface methods are not extension methods.

Edit 1: I believe properties of interfaces worked fine.

Edit 2: actually included error and updated GetHashCode() call to actually reflect GetHashCode() sig.

Comment: _"Getting the following error"_ - you didn't include the error!

Comment: We need to see the interfaces.  For instance I'd think `GetHashCode` would return an `int` and not a `string`, but we cannot be sure without the definition of `ToggleUi`

Comment: I foolishly added a bad line of code in that `GetHashCode()` call.  Updated to return an int.

Comment: The return types weren't matching up.  It works now.

Comment: @juharr drove right down into it and sealed this one off.  I was returning the wrong types!